# Expected value of 3 20-sided dice throws

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have 20 sided dice, which has number 1 on 5 of its sides, 2 and 3 and 4 on another 5 sides each. We throw the dice 3 times.

What is the Expected value of the sum of the throws? What is the Expected value of their multiplication product?

From how I get it, it is the same as if the dice had only 4 sides with 1,2,3 and 4. Each of which has the probability of $\frac{1}{4}$. After 3 throws I would expect the sum to be $3*2.5$ and their product $2.5^3$. Is this correct? How would you write it formally?

Comment: are the dice fair?

Comment: Assuming each side is equally likely, for the expected sum you are correct thanks to linearity of expectation.  For the expected product, your calculation needs independence of throws, and if you have that then you are correct.

Comment: @BCLC yes, they are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thoughts are correct. For a formal statement, denote with $X_i$ the result of throw $i$ for $i=1,2,3$. Then you want to find $E[X_1+X_2+X_3]$ and $E[X_1X_2X_3]$. Now, since the rolls are independent and identically distributed (with uniform distribution on $\{1,2,3,4\}$ as you correctly have - this is the $1/4$ probability) you have that $$E[X_1+X_2+X_3]=3E[X_1]$$ and $$E[X_1X_2X_3]=E[X_1]E[X_2]E[X_3]=(E[X_1])^3$$ with $E[X_1]=2.5$ as you correctly have it.

Comment: @Mykybo. In my answer is not clearly mentioned that independence is needed only for the product. The linearity of expectation holds anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about the sum. Expected values are linear, so the expectation of a sum is the sum of the individual expectations:

$$E[X_1+X_2+X_3]=E[X_1]+E[X_2]+E[X_3]$$

regardless whether the three variables are independent.

For the product we need the additional hypothesis that the variables are independent. In that case you can prove the correctness of your reasoning by using

$$E[(X_i-E[X_i])(X_j-E[X_j])]=0,\ i\neq j.$$

Comment: I think you meant $E[X_1]+E[X_2] + E[X_3]$ for the sum? And aren't the variables independent? What we threw with our first throw, does not in any way affect what we throw the second or third time, no?

Comment: Corrected, thanks. I just wanted to point out that the sum rule is generally safe whatever the variables are.